# check second parameter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in c# mvc, and I am trying to make a route with multiple parameters that looks like this:

**controller/action/parameterOne/parameterTwo**

but in some cases I'm gonna just use one of them so the route will look like this:

**controller/action/parameterOne**

here is my RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:"Default2",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

now in my controller's action I need to check if there is only one parameter or two so I can return a different view for each condition, here is the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult someAction(string category, string id)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
                return View("viewOne");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("ViewTwo");
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the if statement is not full working? because if the conditoin is this: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)`

and if I write **controller/action/parameterOne** this return the ViewOne

but if I write **controller/action/parameterOne/parameterTwo** also return the ViewOne

but now if a invert the condition and I write `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)` both urls return ViewTwo.

So does any one have any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any objection to only using the default route? The only drawback that comes to mind is if you really want your url to look a certain way in which case you may need to define multiple routes as youre trying to do. However, the following should work with only the default route:

```
//note controller actions will default to HttpGet if no data annotation is explicitly supplied. Also, action names generally begin uppercase by convention
public ActionResult SomeAction(string category, string id = null)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
    {
        return View("viewOne");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ViewTwo");
    }
}
```

the various requests you mentioned would look like:

www.myhost.com/controller/someaction?category=parameterOne&id=parameterTwo

or

www.myhost.com/controller/someaction?category=parameterOne